How can I programatically authenticate a user in Auth.js?
I have a Django application with authenticated (logged-in) users.
UPDATE: using the built-in django authentication.
I have another (Svelte) application using Auth.js (https://authjs.dev) for authentication, currently set up with github/facebook/linkedin.
Now I want to send a user from the Django application to the Svelte application, and automagically (i) create the user in the Svelte application if they don't exist, and (ii) log them in to the Svelte application.
I want the end-user experience to be like a regular redirect from one page to the other staying logged-in in both places.
I'm stuck at the part where the user arrives in the Svelte application and I need to create a session. Does Auth.js have any way of doing this without going through a "provider"?
What I have so far is (routes/api/sso/+server.ts):
import { redirect } from '@sveltejs/kit'

export async function GET({url, locals, cookies}) {  // should perhaps be POST..?
    // TODO: validate request..

    // where to go next?
    const next = url.searchParams.get('next')
    if (!next) throw new Error("next is required")

    // who are we logging in?
    const usr = get_or_create(url.searchParams('username')) // and name/email/image/etc.

    // mimic auth.js login behavior...
    const session_token = create_new_session_token()
    locals.session = {
        id: session_token,
        user: {name: usr.name, email: usr.email, image: usr.image}
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2) // two hours
    }
    locals.user = usr
    // ..this might be the only line needed (I'm guessing auth.js will set locals.{session,user} next time it receives a request)?
    cookies.set("authjs.session-token", session_token, {path: "/", httpOnly: true, secure: true, sameSite: "strict"})

    return redirect(307, next)
}


This question is a bit vague, are you using the builtin authentication backend for Django (so username + password) or are you using some different backend? Simplest thing for you would probably be something like using a common OAuth provider.

Hi @AbdulAzizBarkat, I updated the question, but yes, django default username + password. We have thousands of users there already so moving to a common oauth provider would be a pain (I'm also trying to limit the "chatter" between django and svelte during the sso handover since this is a critical path for us (hundreds of users hitting the "button" at the same time - not all on good networks).

Not posting an answer since it's just a vague direction but you could make the Django app itself an OAuth provider, and then maybe in the links sending the user to your Svelte app include some query string that tells the app to authenticate using your Django apps provider (There will probably be some back and forth redirects to complete the flow but it could work)

@AbdulAzizBarkat I thought about that, and it would be a full oauth flow, except the user would never see a login screen when they were redirected back to Django (since they are already logged in there). It just seems like a lot of back-and-forth just to end up in the same spot.

I am not sure how you are maintaining the users in backend. Both your Django and Svelet app should be referring to the same user table on authjs. In that case simply passing the auth Headers should be sufficient.

In this case the Django app does a lot of other work, and the Svelte/Auth.js app is a single task app. It only really need to know that Django vouches for the user being allowed into the Svelte system to do one task. Technically the Svelte/auth.js app doesn't even need any personal data - although we want to send the name for personalization. The Svelte/auth.js app should not have access to the full Django user-profile. It is a pretty standard single-sign-on design where Svelte/auth.js has to trust that Django has done auth/auth.

So your svelte app talks to your django app backend?

It shouldn't be needed. They need to share a secret, which can be handled through an admin interface/manual process. When this secret is present in the Django -> Svelte communication (think Bearer Token), then svelte can be confident that the communication is legitimate and that it should let the user "in" (ie. create a session cookie - and the corresponding user/account/session records in the auth.js tables). Https should prevent MITM attacks, the shared seecret ensures that Svelte knows it really is Django calling. To prevent replay attacks there should probably be a msg id or timestamp.

The Django app generates a signed, secure token and redirects the user to the Svelte app, passing the token as part of the URL or a POST body. The Svelte app validates the token with Django.
To implement this use a secure method to generate a token in Django. You can use itsdangerous, a built-in Django signing module, or JWTs.
In your Svelte app's SSO endpoint (routes/api/sso/+server.ts), create a session for the user using Auth.js's session management.
Auth.js sessions rely on cookies. After creating or updating the user in the Svelte app, you can use Auth.js's built-in cookies to manage the session.
Here are the amended codes:


import { redirect } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import { verifyTokenWithDjango } from '$lib/auth'; // Token validation helper
import { prisma } from '$lib/server/prisma'; // Database helper
import { createSession } from '$lib/server/auth'; // Auth.js session helper

export async function GET({ url, cookies }) {
    // Extract query parameters
    const token = url.searchParams.get('token');
    const next = url.searchParams.get('next') || '/';

    // Validate inputs
    if (!token) throw new Error('SSO token is required');
    if (!next) throw new Error('The "next" parameter is required');

    // Step 1: Validate the token with Django
    const userInfo = await verifyTokenWithDjango(token);
    if (!userInfo) {
        throw new Error('Invalid or expired SSO token');
    }

    // Extract user info from the validated token
    const { email, username, name, image } = userInfo;

    // Step 2: Create or update the user in database
    const user = await prisma.user.upsert({
        where: { email },
        update: { username, name, image },
        create: { email, username, name, image }
    });

    // Step 3: Create a session using Auth.js - compatible logic
    const { sessionToken, sessionExpires } = await createSession(user, cookies);

    // Step 4: Set the session token in the cookies
    cookies.set('authjs.session-token', sessionToken, {
        path: '/',
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        sameSite: 'strict',
        expires: sessionExpires
    });

    // Step 5: Redirect to next page
    return redirect(307, next);
}




Reminder: Answers generated by artificial intelligence tools are not allowed on Stack Overflow. Learn more

Am I correct in assuming that auth.js doesn't have functionality similar to Django's login function (which creates/rotates the sessions and csrf cookies, and sets the session cookie) and that I must do it myself? Step 4 (and possibly step 3) is problematic, since I would be messing with "private" parts of auth.js - which are likely to break during upgrades. Any advice?
